# String traversal using pointers

Tags: c, pointers, c-strings, pointer-arithmetic

I am trying to print every fourth character of a string using pointers.

I was able to achieve it using the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){

char* string = "WhatTheeHell";
char* p = string;

while(*p != '\0'){
    printf("%c\n", *p);
    p += 4;
}

return 0;

}
```

This correctly gives the output to me as:

> W
>
> T
>
> H

Now, I tried another way to do it, which according to my knowledge of pointer arithmetic, should have worked, since the size of int on my machine is 4 bytes.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

int main(int argc, char const *argv[]){


    char* string = "WhatTheeHell";
    int* p = (int*)string;

    while(*p != '\0'){
        printf("%c\n", *p);
        p += 1;
    }

    return 0;

}
```

When I print the output for this, it gives me WTH followed by four newlines.

My question, why are the four newlines being printed? Shouldn't it be that after the H is printed, the *p gives a NULL character present at the end of the string literal and the loop gets terminated?

Comment: Why would `*p` be `0` when it includes 3 more bytes beyond the array? It's undefined behaviour.

Comment: **3 errors** in one: array out of bounds, misaligned accesses, and strict aliasing violations.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For starters the first program is invalid. If a string has the number of characters that is not divisible by `4` you will have undefined behavior because the pointer can point to beyond the string using the pointer arithmetic

```
p += 4;
```

A valid approach can look the following way as it is shown in the demonstrative program

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main( void )
{
    const char *s = "WhatTheeHell";
    const size_t STEP = 4;

    if ( *s )
    {
        const char *p = s;
        do
        {
            printf( "%c\n", *p );
            for ( size_t i = 0; i < STEP && *p; ++i, ++p );
        } while ( *p );            
    }
}
```

Its output is

```
W
T
H
```

The second your program is also invalid. For starters it is not necessary thet a string literal is aligned by `sizeof( int )` (moreover in general the `sizeof( int )` can be greater or less than 4). So the program already has undefined behavior.

In this condition

```
*p != '\0'
```

there are compared `sizeof( int )` bytes (not a single byte ) with the integer constant `'\0'`. So the comparison will be always `true` when the pointer points inside the string (and even beyond the string if there are no zero bytes).

By the way also pay attention to that in C `sizeof( '\0' )` is equal to `sizeof( int )`.

Answer (score 3):

When you compare `*p` to `\0`, `*p` is not a single char but a (presumably) four-byte value (the char is promoted to integer before comparison).
Nothing guaranties that after the `\0` of your string there are other zero bytes: this is undefined behaviour.

Thus your loop continues until it reaches *by chance* a zero integer.

When printing with `"%c\n"`, only the lower byte of the integer is considered; if its value is zero (nothing is guaranteed) it does not print anything visible, just the following `\n`

Comment: Yeah, I thought that was the problem too. But then, how is it printing the W too? I mean, when it dereferences the first time, it should print W followed by the next three bytes right, since W just takes one byte?